# Kotlin regular expression has no match

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am practicing regular expressions in Kotlin and trying to start with a simple string. However, I am not receiving any matches. I feel like I am doing it right and can't figure out the problem.

Test String:
`VERSION_ID="12.2"`

And what would I do this for multiple lines:

```
NAME="SLED"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12 SP2"
ID="sled"
ID_LIKE="suse"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sled:12:sp2"
```

Regex:
`private val myRegex = Regex("VERSION_ID=(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)")`

I am simply trying to match `12.2` from the test string.

https://regex101.com/r/9IG8cO/1

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to match the `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version ID value inside your string appears to be surrounded with double quotes.  Also, I suggest making the decimal portion optional, in case some versions might not have a minor version component:

```kotlin
private val myRegex = Regex("VERSION_ID=\"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\"")
```

Comment: How would I do this if there were multiple lines? I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: The regex patterns we are using should still be equally valid, because although the entire text might span multiple lines, the text you want to capture sits on a single line.